# LINQ using multiple .join extensions with multiple (4) or more tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, join

I am having issues setting up a LINQ query using that is using multiple (4) tables from my database. I am able to join two tables without an issue using the LINQ syntax I am learning, but more than that is giving me trouble. I am attempting to convert the SQL query below into LINQ format.

```
select count(distinct applicant)
from apps inner join
     stu_terms on applicant = student_id inner join
     acad_prog on apps_program = acad_program and st_acad_lvl = acad_lvl inner join
     application_statuses on apps_status = application_status
where st_active_cred >= 0 and apps_start_term = @term and
      apps_admit_status = @status and apps_stu_type = @type and
      application_code is not null
```

I am new to LINQ queries and how everything fits together, but this is what I came up with. It is a little tricky because along with there being 4 tables, the where clause is pulling from three of the different tables and the way I set it up is forcing me to scatter the .Where() method in my query. See below:

```
int num = db.apps.Distinct()
            .Join(db.application_statuses,
            a => a.apps_status,
            aa => aa.application_status,
            (a, aa) => new { apps = a, application_statuses = aa })
            .Where(j => j.apps.admit_status == status && j.apps.apps_stu_type == type && j.apps.apps_start_term == term && j.application_statuses.application_code != null)
                .Join(db.stu_terms,
                a => a.apps.applicant,
                st => st.student_id,
                (a, st) => new { apps = a, stu_terms = st })
                .Where(j => j.stu_terms.st_active_cred >= 0)
                    .Join(db.acad_prog,
                    a => a.apps.apps.apps_program,
                    ap => ap.acad_program,
                    (a, ap) => new { apps = a, acad_prog = ap })
                        .Join(db.stu_terms,
                        ap => ap.acad_prog.acad_lvl,
                        st => st.st_acad_lvl,
                        (ap, st) => new { acad_prog = ap, stu_terms = st }).Count();
```

As you can see, the Where method is in two separate places because it would only be able to see the columns from the specific table in those spots. Majority of problems I am seeing is because I am unaware if I am even joining these four tables together properly. Most of this stuff is still new to me (the random placement of the Distinct() method shows that)

I appreciate the help.

Comment: if your query is so complex don't do it with linQ

Comment: What is this? Linq2SQL or EntityFramework?
Do you have any relations in your model?

Comment: @fhogberg This is Entity Framework. And I do not believe so. These tables have columns that contain like data, but are not FK(s) to each other.

Comment: This really isn't the right tool for the job. If you can't change the model. Stick with the SQL. Get rid of EF alltogether if all your model looks like this and use SqlCommand instead. EF will cause you nothing but pain.

Comment: @fhogberg I'm starting to realize that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ already has the joins in your domain model ( remember ICollection if you are using Code-First)

So you don't need to specify the joins. It uses lazy loading by default, which means the joins are automaticly created when you use them ( = call .ToList() ).

Eg.

```
db.Apps.Where(el => el.Students.Any(dl => dl.Type == 'Something')).ToList()
```

If you want some faster performance, you can use eager loading with Include. Which creates the joins from the start.

```
db.Apps.Include(el => el.Students.Select(dl => dl.childOfStudents))
```

Since you're new. You should also know that all your queries are tracked for changes, which reduces performance.

So if you don't need to change+update objects, use .AsNonQueryable() for slightly better performance.

PS. You can still use SQL --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592907(v=vs.113).aspx :)

Comment: The way the DB I am working with is setup, I think just using raw SQL queries is going to save me a lot of headache. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You **very** rarely use Join() in LINQ with databases.  Instead you just navigate the Navigation Properties.  With a proper model this is as simple as  :

```
      var q = from a in apps
              where a.StuTerms.ActtiveCredits > 0
                 && a.StartTerm = startTerm
                 && a.ApplicationStatus.AdmitStatus = admitStatus
                 && a.StudentType = studentType
                 && a.application_code != null
              select a;

     var applicants = q.GroupBy(a => a.ApplicantId).Count();
```

David

Comment: Seeing OP's comment above, this seems one of those rare cases. But maybe, as an alternative, you could demonstrate that query syntax is much easier anyway, also with joins. By the way, there's no `select` in your query.

Comment: "this seems one of those rare cases"

I don't think so.  You don't need real FKs in the database to declare Navigation Properties and Foreign Key columns in the EF Model.